# Slow VNC / Desktop Sharing Performance from Windows to 13.10

Tags: 13.10, vnc

Running 13.10 and trying to connect from a Windows box over VNC. The performance is incredibly slow even over a LAN connection. Is there anything I can do to fix this or at least improve it?

Answer (score 0):

Many VNC servers are slow, I advise you look at FreeNX.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX

For the windows sever/client go to : http://www.nomachine.com/

FreeNX is both faster and more secure (IMO) then VNC